# Is it possible to send a user to a specific page depending on what account they sign in with?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In the properties tab of the login form, I set the DestinationPageUrl setting to the `adminmenu.aspx` page, but this will mean that even if a student log's on they will be taken to this page, I am looking for a solution that allows the login form to take the user to whatever page they are allowed to view.

So as an example, the login page shows up, and the user that logs in happens to have a student role, the log in form will then take them to the `student.aspx` page, and if another person uses the same login form and they have the admin credentials it takes them to the `adminmenu.aspx` page.

I am having trouble googling for this solution, I was hoping I could get some guidance with this, the only current workaround I have for this would be to have multiple login forms, and each one pointing to a different page.

This is of course using the asp.net website management tool and roles/users ect.

Comment: You can use [role management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.ASPX)

Answer (score 1):

You can add some logic to your login form to redirect based on user role.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default.aspx");
    }
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Student"))
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Student/Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add logic to your login page to redirect you based on role. One idea is to pull the user and the role as part of the authentication.

Example code:

```
if(user.Role == "Student")
{  
   Response.Redirect("Student.aspx");
}
else if(user.Role == "Admin")
{  
   Response.Redirect("Admin.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Role-Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.ASPX) of asp.net.
You can get good example on msdn for the same.
Here is a good link http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs